# Create a breadcrumb with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ncybreadcrumb

I am trying to use [angular-breadcrumb](https://github.com/ncuillery/angular-breadcrumb)
If I use `'ncy-angular-breadcrumb'` to add the dependency I get an error

> Module `'ncy-angular-breadcrumb'` is not available! You either
>   misspelled the module name or forgot to load it

If I use `ng-breadcrumbs` to add the dependency I don't get any result when I use `<div ncy-breadcrumb>` 
I just want to make a breadcrumb, I don't have to use this one.

Comment: Are you sure the script is loaded in `index.html`?

Comment: Make sure you've included it in your page, `<script src="[...]angular-breadcrumb.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my configuration for:

"angular-breadcrumb": "~0.4.1",

From https://github.com/ncuillery/angular-breadcrumb/wiki/Getting-started:

In your angular global app module make sure added

```
angular.module(
'GlobalApp', [...,'ncy-angular-breadcrumb',...])....
```

finally to use the module : 
in js :

```
   ...
   ncyBreadcrumb: {
        label: 'MyLabel'
    }
   ...
```

in html:

```
 <div ncy-breadcrumb></div>
```

Make you've included the module in your page :

```
 <script src=".../angular-breadcrumb.js"></script>
```